# Can't install LibreOffice on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, libreoffice, windows-installer

I've just downloaded LibreOffice 4.1.3 (twice) on a newly refurbished Windows 7 Thinkpad. When I click the .msi to install, I get "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package"

How do I obtain a usable copy of LibreOffice for Windows?

I also tried 4.1.2 and 4.0.6 also, after 4.1.3 failed. 4.1.2 started fine, but encountered an error and failed to install. 4.0.6 fails in the same way as 4.1.3.

I have used 7-zip to test the 4.1.3 msi, and it is unable to open it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you obtained a corrupted file, even if you downloaded it twice, it also sometimes happen to me, just re-download your file, preferably from a mirror, because this might be due to bad communication between you and the server.

Comment: I downloaded again, from a different mirror, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should **check the MD5 checksum** or the **PGP signature** of the msi file. Only after verifying the checksum you can be sure that you've received the file intact. Also, there may be an issue with the download mirror, so you could try to download it from another mirror.

For infos **how** to check the checksum on a Win7 system, see [**`this q/a`**](https://superuser.com/q/245775/84724). For reasons **why** to check the checksum, see [**`this q/a`**](https://superuser.com/q/326959/84724).

**Checksums, signatures and additional download links** can be obtained using the **`Info`** link on the [**main download page**](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/):

[image: LibreOffice Download]

Comment: If my question was "How do I verify that my copy is corrupt" this might be a good answer. My question was: "Do I get a usable copy"

Comment: Ok, i didn't expect that this point would be crucial - so to comply to your needs, i've edited my answer... –

Comment: It may seem trivial to you, but if the goal is to get it working, a second verification that it isn't working provides little help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though when you mouse-over the link it appears to be a direct download to the msi (http://donate.libreoffice.org/home/dl/win-x86/4.2.5/en-US/LibreOffice_4.2.5_Win_x86.msi, for example), it's really a separate webpage. Don't right click and download the link, left click the link and download from there.

Comment: So what? If you right click or left click, file is downloading. Could you please explain it furthermore?

Comment: @Renju-Chandran-chingath: Because the link is not the file, "it's really a separate webpage." You have to click through to the _real_ download page. http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/ is a landing page, it is not where you actually download the file.

Comment: My question is about the difference between the two downloads happening. when i click http://donate.libreoffice.org/home/dl/win-x86/4.2.5/en-US/LibreOffice_4.2.5_Win_x86.msi or the http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh I am getting an insatller file. I am asking about the difference between the two downloaded files?.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath: Right now they are the same files. One is the specific version (4.2.5) and the other is where they'll put the latest version.